# How to switch from 256GB to 500GB M.2 SSD on a new Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: ssd, disk-cloning, m.2

I'm planning to purchase a Windows 10 laptop that has 256GB M.2 SSD. However, I would like to have more storage capacity and I believe 500GB M.2 SSD is much better for my applications. I don't know if the existing 256GB M.2 device is SATA or NVMe SSD, and I don't know if the laptop comes with a Windows installation medium.

The trouble is the M.2 attachment of the SSD. If the SSD used SATA, I could simply use an external SATA dock that attaches to a USB port to clone the disk. However, I'm not sure if it's even possible to build M.2 to USB translator that works in all cases, as M.2 devices may use NVMe.

So, how can I copy the contents from the existing M.2 SSD to the new larger M.2 SSD? I would like the solution to be as cheap as possible, so purchasing a new computer with two M.2 ports is out of the question, and purhasing a new copy of the Windows 10 operating system to reinstall it is also somewhat too expensive.

Although I specified the disk-cloning tag, reinstallation is also an option if it's possible to do without purchasing a new copy of Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create install media off the old disk, swap in the new disk, then install. The key should be locked to the hardware

I'd also consider creating a backup using whatever imaging software you prefer, and restoring it (it'll need a external drive big enough for the old drive) - I did this with veem, but any decent one would do restoration to a bigger (or even a smaller) drive.